# iOs push notifications don't work in production mode

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apns-php

I developed an app using push notifications. To send notifications I used PHP code. I followed the following tutorial: [The tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

The tutorial works correctly with the development mode, but in production mode doesn't work. I repeated the tutorial using the aps_production certificate and reusing the same private key getting from the keychain.

When I execute the php I receive a successfully message but the device doesn't receive the notification. I was trying to solve the problem and I couldn't do it. I know that the device token is different and I'm using the correct token because the app sends it to a server that stores it.

Comment: I presume you changed to using the production server and not the development server in the php script?

Comment: If you mean if I'm using this "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195" in the php instead "ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195" the answer is yes. I'm using the first one.

Comment: Presumably you must also be additionally signing the pushes with the production stuff instead of/as well as the dev stuff. Sorry there's no apparent obvious reason why it should fail. Can you switch back to dev pushes and that still works? THis is a useful reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: Yes, if I connect my device to xcode and execute the app in dev mode, changing the file called ck.pem in the tutorial everything works. For this reason it could be some problem creating the ck.pem file but I follow the same steps than in dev mode. If anybody know other system to send push notifications using php I could use it. Thanks ;)